# Is there a better way to delete data extension records with Server-Side Javascript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I`m going to delete mulitiple data extension records with Server-Side Javascript, so I used function of 'Platform.Function.DeleteData' and code as following:

```
Platform.Function.DeleteData("Map Tags With Emails", ["Email ID"], arrayEmailIds);
```

Here 'arrayEmailIds' is a variable of array type, but it is not to works. Then I change the code as following:

```
var emailIds = Request.GetFormField("emailIds");
var arrayEmailIds = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(emailIds);
for (var i = 0; i < arrayEmailIds.length; i++) {
    Platform.Function.DeleteData("Map Tags With Emails", ["Email ID"], [arrayEmailIds[i]]);
}
```

It works properly, even so I think it is not a good way to do this, so I want to get a better method to involve this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your process uses the API in order to delete the rows. There is also a SSJS function for deleting data extension rows.  To be honest, I'm not sure which approach is best.

For more information on the SSJS function, refer to the **Remove(filtercolumns,filtervalues)** function on the following page.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsRemove.htm

Comment: Hi David, I tried it but it didn`t work.
I changed the code as following:
var mapDE = DataExtension.init("MapTagsWithEmails");
mapDE.Rows.Remove(["Email ID"], [arrayEmailIds]);

Comment: I think you need to adjust the syntax slightly.  Each parameter in the remove function needs to be in name value pairs.  Will something like this work for you?  
  ------  
var mapDE = DataExtension.init("MapTagsWithEmails"); 
mapDE.Rows.Remove(["Email ID", "value"]);

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo about the 'init', it should to be 'Init'.

Comment: And I don`t think your codes is right, because the syntax was wrong, I tried.

Comment: the link looks broken.  Kindly update the link please

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy I've updated the link above to point to Marketing Cloud's new documentation site.